# How to create a test with the React Lazy + Fallback + Children component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to create some tests to check for the following conditions in the `App.tsx` component:

1. Has my "`Router`" component been rendered?
2. Does my fallback have a loading container?

Among others.. But I am getting the following error message:

```
A React component suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified.

    Add a <Suspense fallback=...> component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display.
```

**MY COMPONENT:**

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

// React Lazy Components
const Router = React.lazy(() => import('components/router'));

const App = (): JSX.Element => (
    <>
        <Suspense data-testid='suspense-component' fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
            <Router data-testid='router-component' />
        </Suspense>
    </>
);

export default App;
```

**MY TEST:**

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { render, screen, getByTestId } from '@testing-library/react';

const App = React.lazy(() => import('App'));
const Router = React.lazy(() => import('components/router'));

describe('Testing App.tsx', () => {
    test('should check the lazy component (Routers)', async () => {
        const { debug, baseElement } = render(<App />);

        debug(baseElement);

        expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
        // expect(screen.getByText(/loading.../i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

**How do I fix it?**

I don't know if it's possible, but instead of instantiating Suspense in the test file, use Suspense from the component file.